# How to purge strange files in lost+found

Tags: filesystems, centos6

somehow i did end ip with a 'lot' of corrupted files in lost+found directory (centos) and I can't get rid of them.

Any idea ?

```
[/lost+found]# ls -la
total 196
drwx------  5 root       root       16384 15 nov 11:22 .
dr-xr-xr-x 24 root       root        4096 15 nov 12:00 ..
dr-s-wSrw-  2 2770915992 3548817360  8192 24 nov  1945 #116218
---sr---w-  1 1706202106 2512835934 49152  9 aoû  1912 #117788
--wx-wxr--  1 1583224319  391770300 49152 23 sep  1981 #118171
--ws-wS-w-  1 1646925659  410402836 49152  5 jui  1982 #118172
drw--wxrwT  2 1827674601  463260682  8192 27 oct  1983 #118174
-r-xrwxr-T  1 1872119673 1210446066 49152 13 jan  2008 #119226
---s-wsr--  1 2928826225 1483781972 49152  5 aoû  2016 #120124
d-wxr-s--T  2 1136296390 2183236452  8192 29 nov  1902 #121464
```

Answer (score 2):

First [read about what the `lost+found` directory is, and understand what those files are.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix)
Do ***NOTHING*** until you have read that question and answer.

---

Now that you know what those files are you can decide if you want to examine them to see if you need their contents for anything.

Save the ones you want, and delete the rest as you would any other file/directory (`rm -f`, or `rm -rf`, you will probably need to do so as root given that the files have seemingly-random UIDs associated with them.

If you are *routinely* winding up with files in the lost & found you may have a bigger problem that you need to investigate (your machine crashes/shuts down uncleanly a lot, or your disk is dying and you're seeing errors manifesting during `fsck` at reboot).